# save Map<String, dynamic> or json raw into flutter application

Tags: flutter

i'm looking for a solution to save data after a api call like userData, cartitem ecc..
I used sharedPreferences but i can't directly save the json or the Map<String, dynamic> inside it
just String or List.

I'd like to store all my data into one place and call single field using varible.field into my app, it is a correct way to build app and it can be done?

Comment: you might consider using Hive package and have the ability to make adapters for your custom classes and save them, since using sharedPreferences will require you to encode & decode to  the Map to JSON in order to get a working mechanism in your app

Answer (score 0):

you can create data in sharedpreferences it is suggested to store small key value pair values in sharedpreferences. but if you have large size of data store it in the database like(SQFlite, Hive) which gives you a lot other features(applying filters on data, accessing data on some condition, making relations etc) in accessing the data.